# Can I Override a Key in a TypeScript Interface?

Tags: typescript, interface, overriding, typescript2.0, type-definition

I know how to extend a TypeScript interface, but what I'm asking here is how to ***override*** a particular key in an interface. For example, say I have a simple interface `A`:

```
interface A {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}
```

And I have another simple interface `B`, also with a `bar` key, but of a different type:

```
interface B {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}
```

Essentially, I want to merge these interfaces into one, giving me the following interface:

```
interface C {
    foo: string; // from A.foo
    bar: string; // from B.bar (overrides A.bar)
    baz: number; // from B.baz
}
```

I wish I could just extend somehow:

```
interface C extends A, B {}
```

But I can't, because I get this error, which is totally expected and by design:

> Interface 'C' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'. Named
>   property 'bar' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.

I'm just not sure if there's another mechanism of which I am unaware. I don't think intersection or union types help here either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little late... but I fixed this issue creating another type...

```
type ExcludeAddress<T> = Omit<T, 'addresses'>;
```

This type excludes a **specific** key (I called 'address') from the interface...

I used it to solve a problem where I needed to cast a value of the interface...
I removed it and then created a new interface extending the old interface(without the key) + an interface with the new keyType...

Example:

```
type ExcludeAddress<T> = Omit<T, 'addresses'>;

export interface IAvailability {
    readonly frequency: number;
    readonly duration: number;
    readonly date: string;
    readonly addresses: Address[];
}

export interface ISerializedAvailability extends ExcludeAddress<IAvailability> {
    readonly addresses: string[];
}
```

You would need to adjust the *ExcludeAddress* I created for you own personal project...
Maybe it's not cleaneast solution, but well... it works

**In my example:** I created *ISerializedAvailability* is essencially an *IAvailability* where **address** has type *string[]* and not *Address[]*

Comment: FYI nowadays `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'addresses'>>` can be written as `Omit<T, 'addresses'>` builtin too

Answer (score 3):

maybe you need ?

```
type UnionOverrideKeys<T, U> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U;
```

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/7658d2994a171270fcc336c9a05d3432.git)

Comment: You are missing link label

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

To explain the reasoning a little deeper than [@Alexandre Dias's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7050326/alexandre-dias) example...

The `&` operator is known as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) type and basically combines or merges two types as best as it can . This is similar to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) type but the union is an `OR` operation rather than an `AND` operation.

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#intersections) it says...

> ```
> type Combined = { a: number } & { b: string };
> type Conflicting = { a: number } & { a: string };
> ```
>
> Combined has two properties, a and b, just as if they had been written as one object literal type. Intersection and union are **recursive** in case of conflicts, so Conflicting.a: number & string.

The important thing to note is the part about it merging the types **recursively**. Thus in your case, `A & B` would result is `bar` being of type `number & string`, which does not make sense and typescript converts this to `never`.

[image]

So any value you set as `bar` will throw a type error.

[image]

So yes the simplest solution to you case would be to just remove (i.e. `Omit`) the duplicate keys from one of the types before intersecting...

```
type CombinedAB = Omit<A, keyof B> & B

//                       hack to just look at types
const test2: CombinedAB = {} as any; 
test2.bar = 'string' // ok
```

See demo typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20TAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG4c8AjOKUkAVwFtHp6BfLFlCRYiFACFMDXM1blKNenmTMAXmy48o-QQHpdyw0eOBeDcDiO8gAWiANbIwBZACt2FZABsiduGHsBPAAcIMiwEAhA3SAoARlJ0ADJkSQBeTD5kODIMkD9aZEEosGiAOkJHVIByMoq8-WQCGyxCkrLkVOjag2goAigC4KLitTbkDuQ6hqaBkuHKtRrxrqgevqmYoZYR6MXkbt61wdkRir2oCp3TwSw6gBVAlGFoMggEMGBw5Chg9ncwLId-EFkCAIAA3aBNe7IACS4CeLzAADkuABlBQgagjDjcaDIRIUKgY%20hhCK%20WEiZ6vADC4Rg7mAr1I5Phr2RnDRhMx7U6u2W%20z0BhRwE4AXcKBRBHc7De4UhQJp3FAEAAJqgUsgAPKcYBgAA8qAANMgbBA-AQYEkAHx4pIC4z20wWawIOwAlxuTwNDK%20MD3EIkyIDABMpAVjCVqvVGHSmWyuXyhSDGygxwJNHOExsQA)

---

Helpful advice...

An **INCREDIBLY** useful tool for troubleshooting typescript types is [`piotrwitek/utility-types`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types). This is a library of dozens of useful types to build off of the native built-in typescript types. I would highly advise adding this as a `devDependencey` to use whenever you need. It includes many improvements to native types as well like allowing keys for `Required<T, K>`.

The type that would solve your issue here is [`Overwrite<T, U>`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#overwritet-u) (*From U overwrite properties to T*), then you can simply go into their [src code](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types/blob/df2502ef504c4ba8bd9de81a45baef112b7921d0/src/mapped-types.ts#L313-L327) and look at how the type works...

```
/**
 * Overwrite
 * @desc From `U` overwrite properties to `T`
 * @example
 *   type Props = { name: string; age: number; visible: boolean };
 *   type NewProps = { age: string; other: string };
 *
 *   // Expect: { name: string; age: string; visible: boolean; }
 *   type ReplacedProps = Overwrite<Props, NewProps>;
 */
export type Overwrite<
  T extends object,
  U extends object,
  I = Diff<T, U> & Intersection<U, T>
> = Pick<I, keyof I>;
```

> Note: `Diff` and `Intersection` are two of their custom types.

Looking at how they effectively use more complex typescript types like [conditionals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content) and [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) lets you understand and create even the most complex types like [`DeepPartial`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61233706/6943587)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union type: `type C = A | B;` but then both of these work fine:

```
let c1: C = {
    foo: "string",
    bar: "string",
    baz: 3
};

let c2: C = {
    foo: "string",
    bar: 4,
    baz: 3
};
```

Comment: Yes, a union and an override are different. In this case, `bar` should not be allowed to be a `number`.

Comment: Right, but you can't override a property

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm going to accept your answer, seeing as the answer is actually "no".