# How to pull null check into function in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, null

I have some code where I have several functions that need to null check an object then do stuff with it, or throw an error if it's null, like so:

```js
interface SomeObject {
    doThingOne: () => string;
    doThingTwo: () => string;
}

let object: SomeObject | null; 

function doThingOne() {
  if(!object) {
    throw new Error('Object is null!');
  }
  // Typescript knows that object is not null, so it's fine with accessing its properties/methods
  return object.doThingOne();
}

function doThingTwo() {
  if(!object) {
    throw new Error('Object is null!');
  }
  return object.doThingTwo();
}
```

I'd like to pull out the null check into a function to reduce the duplicated code, like so:

```js
interface SomeObject {
    doThingOne: () => string;
    doThingTwo: () => string;
}

let object: SomeObject | null; 

function requireObject() {
  if(!object) {
    throw new Error('Object is null!');
  }
}

function doThingOne() {
  requireObject();
  // Typescript no longer knows that object is defined, so it gets mad at the next line
  return object.doThingOne();
}

function doThingTwo() {
  requireObject();
  return object.doThingTwo();
}
```

However, when I do so, typescript is no longer aware that after the check, `object` definitely exists. Is there a clean way to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715352/how-can-a-function-check-for-null-in-typescript) seems similar, but wouldn't actually let me save on much code repetition as I'd still need to set up an `if`

Comment: This is very confusing, I'm not entire sure what you're asking, also when does doThingOne/doThingTwo extend object into a method? And why use a seperate function? What is the goal? Could you make a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm just trying to reduce repetition. `object`, if it exists, is of a type that has some methods on it. The issue's the same regardless of if I want to call `object.doThingOne()` or use `object.someProperty`.

Comment: Here's a code example with errors on the preferred approach: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZa5AE3QBUALUAcxxAgC5kAKASmQBeAHzIAzmChsA3FRr1mbBgHd0PAcLGTpIVnIC+FCgBsIpdIWJgeGbPiIlkAH2QgAriZMzkFGO5ASYHQQOkYWPQ4ITUpqYBheAEJLRzBBWJowJih0FTcIPIBRKByoXgByB2tkYHE3TxNE8v45aiNqKHN3KFCU6wA6RQj2TgFDY39AsGDQoeU1GPl4pL6SdPlqLJy8ziKS9DLKqyda+q8mlvl25E6wbt7jsEHw+fQxiiM-AKCQm4gAR3cwE6VRIiziCWSj3WNGQW1y+T2pQqoNIpw852arWQRk+kx+sxekU4ACZwX9AcDcI8BPJbvdkKsnnNidFLnjvtNfizWKp0GSYRSgSCafw6V0eozHs8lHo+e8DEA

Comment: There's no way to have a function call like `requireObject()` affect the state of arbitrary in-scope values.  You can an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to get similar results but you need to pass in the guarded thing as an argument, like `requireObject(object)`.  See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wX2BDm).  If this approach meets your needs I can write up an answer, otherwise the answer is basically "no, you can't do this" which I *could* write up as an answer, I suppose, maybe.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Assertion functions seem like just what I'm looking for!

Comment: So, do you want me to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to write `requireObject()` and have that affect the type of `object`, since the compiler does not see `requireObject()` as related to `object` in any way.  (If the compiler could manage all possible state changes due to mutation of closed-over variables inside functions, that would be great, but it's just not computationally feasible.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for the general problem.)

What you can do is pass `object` into `requireObject()` and annotate that `requireObject()` is an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).  Assertion functions must be implemented as `void`-returning (so they don't return anything), and the annotated return type is an "assertion predicate" of the form `asserts x is Y` (where `x` is the name of one of the function parameters) or just `asserts x` if you want to say that `x` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

So that gives us:

```
function requireObject(x: any): asserts x {
  if (!x) {
    throw new Error('something is falsy here');
  }
}
```

And now we can do this without error:

```
let object: SomeObject | null;

function doThingOne() {
  requireObject(object);
  return object.doThingOne(); // okay
}

function doThingTwo() {
  requireObject(object);
  return object.doThingTwo(); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZAE3QBUALUAcxxAgC5kAKASmQBeAHzIAzmCisA3FVoNmIFvQDu6bvyGiJUpbIC+FCgBsIpdIWJhuGbPiIlkAH2QgArseOyKMNyBLA6CDIUBAAjm7AofZWPAAe3HAgAJ58iWJi0GBiyHHkcsAwvACEcQKU1NRgjFDoKq4Q9QCiULVQPADkYlhmiizIwDnwxmLJyIzQEB18stSGhj5+AUHyTKzsEJoVIeGR0ZYkPBYOYDNyoWBuUMHHVgB0dGtKG-wGRr7+YIHBj32q6FtzrsorgDmAjmCztQLlcbmCHgpWP9XhR9EA)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `!` operator to tell the compiler that `object` will definitely contain a value.

```
return object!.doThingOne();
```

I try to avoid that sort of thing. It's easy to get into trouble later on. Instead, I would define the `requireObject` function to always return an object.

```
function requireObject(): object {
    if (!object) {
        throw new Error('Object is null!');
    }
    return object;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
object = requireObject();
```

Since `requireObject` always returns an `object` type, the compiler will know that at that point `object` is not `null`.

The only problem now is, because `object` is actually a TypeScript type, the code is a little confusing. It should work (I haven't actually tried it), but you may want to consider naming the variable something else.