# How can I let one function use the check on a nullable field from another function?

Tags: typescript

I have below code in TypeScript. The function `isDataAvailable` returns true if `data` is not undefined. In `updateData` function, it has a if condition on the `isDataAvailable` return value but the compiler reports an error on `data.i++`: `'data' is possibly 'undefined'.`.

If the `data` has been checked in `isDataAvailable` function already, why does TypeScript still think it could be `undefined`? Is there a way to make it check the previous function return value?

```
let data: { i: number; j: number } | undefined = undefined;

const isDataAvailable = () => {
  return !!data;
};

const updateData = () => {
  if (isDataAvailable()) {
    data.i++;
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull null check into function in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365015/how-to-pull-null-check-into-function-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

They don't deal with globals, though, they need to be arguments to the function:

```
type Data = { i: number; j: number }

const isDataAvailable = (data?: Data): data is Data => {
  return !!data;
};

const updateData = (data?: Data) => {
  if (isDataAvailable(data)) {
    data.i++;
  }
};
```

This is kind of a contrived example, because the above could be represented just by doing:

```
const updateData = (data?: Data) => {
  if (data) {
    data.i++;
  }
};
```

But hopefully type predicates is what you were looking for!