# Ensure subset interface from interface / PickDeep<>?

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way given a interface:

```
interface Person {
  age: number,
  name: string,
  hometown?: {
    city: string,
    zip: number
  }
}

type SubPerson = EnsureSubInterface<Person, {
  name: string
}>
```

this would be valid:

```
const x: SubPerson {
  name: "Tom"
}
```

this would be invalid:

```
const x: SubPerson {
  age: 12
}
```

Comment: Look into [the `Partial<T>` type](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-partial-type-in-typescript-ecfcfbc87cb6).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't believe that is helpful, that would still allow any part of `T` which I' am trying to restrict.

Comment: Why do you say `PickDeep` wouldn't regular Pick work? `Pick<Person, 'name' >`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have deep properties I'd like to also allow for instance `hometown.city` but not `hometown.zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ensure that the second type parameter is a subset of the original at any give level, you could use `DeepPartial` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372227/how-to-implement-typescript-deep-partial-mapped-type-not-breaking-array-properti/49936686#49936686)) as a constraint on the second parameter to `EnsureSubInterface`

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer U>
    ? Array<DeepPartial<U>>
    : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
        ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<U>>
        : DeepPartial<T[P]>
};

type EnsureSubInterface<T, U extends DeepPartial<T>> = U

interface Person {
    age: number,
    name: string,
    hometown?: {
        city: string,
        zip: number
    }
}

type SubPerson = EnsureSubInterface<Person, {
    name: string,
    hometown: {
        city: string,
    }
}>


type NotSubPerson = EnsureSubInterface<Person, {
    name: string,
    hometown: {
        city: number, // error
    }
}>


type NotSubPerson = EnsureSubInterface<Person, {
    name: string,
    hometown: {
        City: string, // error
    }
}>
```

Depending on your tslint config you might want this:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends (infer U)[]
  ? DeepPartial<U>[]
  : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
      ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<U>>
      : DeepPartial<T[P]>
};
```