# Typescript array of objects with enum generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
enum ServicePlugin {
  Plugin1,
  Plugin2,
  Plugin3,
}

interface PluginOptions {
  [ServicePlugin.Plugin1]: { option1: string };
  [ServicePlugin.Plugin2]: { option1: number; option2: number };
}

type PluginOptionsMap = Omit<
  { [key in ServicePlugin]: undefined },
  keyof PluginOptions
> &
  PluginOptions;

type PluginConfig<T extends ServicePlugin> =
  PluginOptionsMap[T] extends undefined
    ? { plugin: T }
    : {
        plugin: T;
        options: PluginOptionsMap[T];
      };

const params: PluginConfig<ServicePlugin>[] = [
  {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin1,
    options: {
      option1: "foo",
    },
  },
  {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin2,
    options: {
      option1: 123,
      option2: 456,
    },
  },
  {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin2,
    options: {
      option1: "bar", // No error here even though it is the wrong options type
    },
  },
  {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin3,
    // Error: 'options' is not declared here
  },
];
```

The type `PluginConfig<ServicePlugin>[]` is behaving more like an array of the union of all the plugins instead of an array of individual plugins. This makes sense, but it is not what I want.

**How can I create an array of generic objects where the generic type of each object is a particular enum value?**

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `PluginConfig` to be a specific (non-generic) [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type, where each member corresponds to a member of the `ServicePlugin` [union enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types).  Like this:

```
type PluginConfig = {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin1;
    options: {
        option1: string;
    };
} | {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin2;
    options: {
        option1: number;
        option2: number;
    };
} | {
    plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin3;
    options?: never;
}
```

Note in the `Plugin3` case I've made `options` an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  That effectively prohibits the `options` property from being present (or at least cannot be anything but `undefined`).  Optional means it's okay to leave it out, and `never` means it's not okay to use it.

---

Anyway we can make the compiler compute `PluginConfig` from the definitions of `ServicePlugin` and `PluginOptions`, via a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)):

```
type PluginConfig = { [K in ServicePlugin]:
    K extends keyof PluginOptions ?
    { plugin: K, options: PluginOptions[K] } :
    { plugin: K, options?: never }
}[ServicePlugin];
```

The general form `{ [K in ServicePlugin]: F<K> }[ServicePlugin]` where we make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `ServicePlugin` and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with `ServicePlugin` effectively *distributes* the `F<K>` operation over the `ServicePlugin` union, so it will become `F<ServicePlugin.Plugin1> | F<ServicePlugin.Plugin2> | F<ServicePlugin.Plugin3>`.

The particular `F<K>` operation we're using is `K extends keyof PluginOptions ? { plugin: K, options: PluginOptions[K] } : { plugin: K, options?: never }`.  That's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  The `plugin` property is just `K` no matter what, but if `K` is a key of `PluginOptions` then the `options` property is the corresponding value, whereas if it is not, then we prohibit `options` by making it an optional-`never` property.

You can verify that it produces a type equivalent to the version above.

---

Let's make sure it works how you want:

```
const params: PluginConfig[] = [
    {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin1,
        options: {
            option1: "foo",
        },
    },
    {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin2,
        options: {
            option1: 123,
            option2: 456,
        },
    },
    {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin2,
        options: {
            option1: "bar", // error,
        },
    }, // Types of property 'options' are incompatible.
    {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin3, // okay
    },
];
```

Looks good.  The third array element is in error because you're using `ServicePlugin.Plugin2` with the options for `ServicePlugin.Plugin1`.  And the last array element is allowed because you've left out the optional `options` property.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYOwrgtgBAysBOA3AlgY2ABQDZgObJCgG8AoKcqbPAgRgBoyKr8QAmBiynFgZgYF8SJAgBcEAMwCG6LtRAB5AA4jkAexABnYo3IBtOEjSZuBAHTNaAXQBcxKKuVqQNWxpHwCuKPwDcOqPoIKOgWIOYmbDZ2DirqLlDgEABGCD72juqstokp8N5+giQiAJ6KwLIsAMLq4sheALx2ugDSUASwQUahNv6twAAeYiAAJloA1sDFquIVBEqxmlAA-P5EUIoRts106QsatqHzThotlt5Q1qvrm1Dbu8dL2cCICN4k-IGGIRGWfiQA9AAqKAlMqzEDVEC1BraTgbOS2AzBYxycJyGh+TgxY62UicLEZZyudyeTEUXzvKAAH1hFHhLERnW+qNCrDJ5Gx6n2tPx9zi2UguXZ+M5bAFyVS-gp-GpPOuCI6XxRLDRvGFoo0jygYBGwFqIGAwwKUEB-yEJFQXJE60k8EkEG5oUh0N0Z0aulW-jhNyRXQiqtoHF5fM0uK9wdF8QAROJVKoo0HefxE94U3jg-SCIylaEA2wUwS9mHgyLCfEaKw+OHeaKslAACwAVgAbAXySnk56S5mQNnkbnWW2OYTuemS8OFtGkraE1B-v8oAh4Kp4EPU1KdvOoAAVUrALTTdbLsrwEpQADkGvPUFt5QIlogikkKiSWGApi7GZ9TOVZlCfDnBdVDGSRig3EhfiEIA)

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is gonna be a lot but bear with me...

#### Cleanup

Firstly, I cleaned up some of your types that really have no functional change but I think it helps to see a cleaner and more logical way of deriving complex types.

The way you compute the `PluginOptionsMap` is hard to understand what is happening, I get that you are saying, basically fill all empty keys with `undefined`.

```
type PluginOptionsMap = Omit<   
  { [key in ServicePlugin]: undefined },    
  keyof PluginOptions   
> & 
  PluginOptions;
```

A cleaner way to do this would be to simply *loop* over the keys of the `ServicePlugin` enum and check does this `key` exist in `PluginOptions`? If it does return the options, otherwise undefined.

```
type PluginOptionsMap = {
  [key in ServicePlugin]: key extends keyof PluginOptions // this check here is require for calling PluginOptions[key]
    ? PluginOptions[key] : undefined
};
```

> Side note - I see you use `key` as the inferred or generic type a lot. I totally understand wanting to enumerate what the thing is but typescript generics can get a bit crazy and long. It is common practice to use `T` and other single capital letters to designate generics so that calling `someThing[T]` in many places doesn't get too long. You can see this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61233706/6943587.
>
> That said it's up to you at the end of the day - just an FYI :)

#### Troubleshooting

Whenever I am troubleshooting a type trying to figure out what may be wrong with the type, I set the type to a variable and hover the type. Using a variable I can also check what properties each nested type has.

[image]

So in the final solution you will see these intermediate types that I use to check. You should delete these when you have your types finalized.

#### Solution

If you look at the resulting type of `PluginConfig<ServicePlugin>[]` you get something like...

```
const testParams: {
    plugin: ServicePlugin;
    options: {
        option1: string;
        option2?: undefined;
    } | {
        option1: number;
        option2: number;
    } | undefined;
}[]
```

The problem here is that typescript assigns the union at the `Params.options` level and not the top level. So this is saying I can have any plugin value as `ServicePlugin` and any `options` value so long as it's one of the options.

The solution is to somehow **force** typescript to create the union of these types at the top-level.

To do this we can just create a simple map like we did for `PluginOptionsMap` but restructure the value into the desired shape.

```
type PluginConfigMap = {
  [T in keyof PluginOptionsMap]: PluginOptionsMap[T] extends undefined ? { plugin: T } : {
    plugin: T;
    options: PluginOptionsMap[T];
  }
};
```

This resulting type would look like...

```
type PluginConfigMap = {
    0: {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin1;
        options: {
            option1: string;
        };
    };
    1: {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin2;
        options: {
            option1: number;
            option2: number;
        };
    };
    2: {
        plugin: ServicePlugin.Plugin3;
    };
}
```

Then we can just take the value of `PluginConfigMap`.

```
import { ValuesType } from 'utility-types';

type PluginConfigs = ValuesType<PluginConfigMap>
```

> Here I use the helper type `ValuesType` from [`utility-types`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types). Highly recommended to see how types are build and simplify your types.

Finally, using this new `PluginConfigs` type we get the expected result...

[image]

See full solution playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgNQIYBsCuBTAzgFQE8xs4BfOAMyghDgHJMZh1gZCBadk3egbgCwAKGHYAdpjoBlbFABuwAMbYAClgDmwMYmFw4azJrEBGADS79GrQCZzQvQaMBmO2WHCtMWZVTLLhrQB5MGYIMVwdezgAbRl5JVUrMQA6Ry1jAF0ALkQ4CBDgMOMc3BgoLXVyQSjY2QVlNJTG62zc-NCTHIkQACNZPjyCsOsuyT6oKuE3ESFuUkbgjtwAWVQwOABeSL1ogGtsQjgtODj6xICxVv3D7AAPLzEAEwjriEp-I0XC8LgAel%204DAABbACKKIHYRS7OAQqCkUFwOEAR0wwDhVGgcEUGFYYkqCyG4T2BwyFj0AH4PkFCbhiYQMnAcpgnthKFpsI8ptV-nAAEp4TDoZh4wHEbDCHlzKliL5hFZrTaRHl6PQABhyCAlAJVOsGHWKcFK5Tx3O1KrIpt1Bs1QmVur07W%20Bu640t9odhJGcBd-S1uotfp1XuZj1Z7MelumfoAqrhSMCETAIIC8PAvKUCUtVusODCIHJZHA5BgcIDk3H42LhIo5WnU5nvvKwDkG3Ls4qEBRUBFUGJCNUY3HASCIkmU6VxzBW%20F25RMdhfECTnUEo04LmgfnC8WsPHy9hKyRq7XJ9Om8ZFemp0lZTO1rV4g0kqkkplj%20E6xmbzTs9ZL-Xvyze9TlXZ9mlJIQaw-U9AMbbMnH-L8LlvJsHzORoXwuJwIOEKVGgAYTCNl1AAHnwOA7geZ5l0fc4jAAPk2Cwz2zaJ8AZSjxGokMwzEDkyTgSkbXtMAkhyfABI9JYumwAsoGqHVph1DVJJVUSLnEhT3UdOUW1gtt73YrTFIHW0AVjeMRzLScMQmBdwRo9CknXPM5KLEs90NA9RSPSCTyvAiiOAdQDUCsRiJIkCnwuTCjGMRitk7OBu2SvtqigicAqSQjwuCr0woiqK6K0WKbASxAux7NL30ygCLhy4inD0%20qgtIoqMMaJxyqSlLe37dw-OggLUCgVAQFwZqjAa4LIpXaKGOiBlEsq1L%20rMxEBSFCofPFdaMs-KcRrGialTNPR1KMHJ2qSN0VR08IVPW909SdEoygqW77Xu6xySZFk2T4iNA3NOAAB9Tuel6ilGXpfSe7TPRh11gb0ChwZ4gGOUjRaBrw7LWvbRKLDYo5tFed4WLWVpKbANiOPuLiIgx8NBNyC6tHE8hGW2NSxLgfBjKhh7pRQ1ijIsaYAxmPGWty9QIi2NBdwIMUSIK4Ls3ogb9rgMAjvGyatGm%20XFsVaILGE3mNMc0CYsaMwBPuk7LZ1e6DQAIjnCB3bsRTffIf2Xd1vnrrtpJbEdmlHq%20wkDWMawXFU76cgAFgAVgANn91H-bIQOBPZsQrrm4qmnD7OhedpPY5yd2ehGn2-gBABRKAaCgCIwjgAB3GgRSdnaBLziX86ic6Q5LjqkkTsem%209ZMQGgUhZHbnuIW0egnfoI4IjECB4FDRR0BGjkYVkXac%20EDI%20CAA)

#### Further reading

- Sometimes unions of objects don't behave well in identifying which to choose. This can be fixed by representing each property across all objects in the union. See article.